# Why the pictureBox1 is empty white when adding images to it?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to play the images from the hard disk as fast as i can in the picturebox1. So far nothing worked fine. So i'm trying to use this method but the pictureBox1 is empty white.

In timer tick event

```
private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
                pictureBox1.Image = GetThumbnail(_files[_indx].FullName);
                timer3.Interval = 40;
                _indx++;
        }
```

And GetThumbnail method

```
private const int THUMBNAIL_DATA = 0x501B;

    Image GetThumbnail(string path)
    {
        FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(path);
        // Last parameter tells GDI+ not the load the actual image data
        Image img = Image.FromStream(fs, false, false);


        // GDI+ throws an error if we try to read a property when the image
        // doesn't have that property. Check to make sure the thumbnail property
        // item exists.
        bool propertyFound = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < img.PropertyIdList.Length; i++)
            if (img.PropertyIdList[i] == THUMBNAIL_DATA)
            {
                propertyFound = true;
                break;
            }

        if (!propertyFound)
            return null;

        PropertyItem p = img.GetPropertyItem(THUMBNAIL_DATA);
        fs.Close();
        img.Dispose();


        // The image data is in the form of a byte array. Write all 
        // the bytes to a stream and create a new image from that stream
        byte[] imageBytes = p.Value;
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes.Length);
        stream.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

        return Image.FromStream(stream);
    }
```

Comment: Cache thumbnails in a `List<Image>`.

Comment: Pretty basic property of a GUI in Windows, painting only occurs when your UI thread doesn't have anything else to do.  Yours does, it is slaving away at generating thumbnails that nobody will ever look at.  If you want the paint to happen earlier then you have to add `pictureBox1.Update();`  Usually works for about 5 seconds, after which Windows steps in to tell the user that trying to stop the crazy flickering isn't going to work.